# C++ ctime with ansi escapes

Tags: c++, ansi-escape

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#define WIDTH 118
#define HEIGHT 60

void clearScreen(void) {
        cout << "\033[2J\n";
}

void moveCursor(int row, int column) {
        cout << "\033[" << row << ";" << column << "H";
}

void waitDelay(int sec) {
        long startTime = time(NULL);
        while(1) {
                long currentTime = time(NULL);
                if (currentTime - startTime > sec) {
                        break;
                }
        }
}

int main() {
        char message[] = "* * * B R E A K * * *";
        int messageLength = (sizeof(message) - 1) / sizeof(message[0]);
        int startMessageCoord = (WIDTH - messageLength) / 2;

        clearScreen();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageLength; ++i) {
                moveCursor((HEIGHT - 1) / 2, startMessageCoord + i);
                cout << message[i]; 
                waitDelay(1);
        }

        moveCursor(HEIGHT, 0);
        return 0;
}
```

My code works only if the "waitDelay(1)" line is commented and idk why. is my waitDelay function wrong?
I expected the message to be outputed letter by letter but instead the program will wait for 20s (delay for all characters) and then will output the full message.

Comment: cout is buffered, if you want to write out each character do a flush after each cout e.g. `cout << message[i] << flush;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `waitDelay` works well. The mistake is here `cout << message[i]`. `cout` is buffered stream. You should use [flush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush)

Answer (score 1):

With `cout` you need to use `endl` to have immediate output. So instead of `cout << message[i];` use `cout << message[i] << endl;`

**EDIT:**
Apparently, `endl` has a side effect of adding a new-line character into the stream, which may not be desirable in the most cases, and particularly in the original question. So yes, the `flush` is the right thing to go with, as already answered and accepted by the OP.